# Retrofit2 - response body null on success request

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm having a problem with Retrofit2.

When I make a call to my webservice, even in case of success, the body of my response is null.

I tried to make the same call with RESTClient for Firefox and the body contains the correct answer.

This is my stack trace:

```
D/Call request: Request{method=POST, url=http://myNeo4jServer.com, tag=null}
D/Call request header: Authorization: Basic xxxxxx
                       Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/Response raw header: Server: nginx
                       Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 10:55:13 GMT
                       Content-Type: application/json
                       Content-Length: 21549
                       Connection: keep-alive
                       Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                       OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1463482513167
                       OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1463482513354
D/Response raw: retrofit2.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody@e6c7df
D/Response code: 200
D/Response body: null
```

As you can see:

- Content-Length: 21549 (I think that counts also the characters in the body)
- Response code: 200
- Response body: null

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

My interface:

```
public interface PhonebookContactAPI {
    @Headers({
        "Authorization: Basic xxxxxx",
        "Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("/db/data/transaction/commit")
    Call<ResponseBody> get(@Body RequestBody body);
}
```

My request:

```
String json = "{\"statements\": [{\"statement\": \"MATCH (n) RETURN n\"}]}";

Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Globals.BASE_CLIENT_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

PhonebookContactAPI service = client.create(PhonebookContactAPI.class);

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);

Call<ResponseBody> call = service.get(body);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        Log.d("Call request", call.request().toString());
        Log.d("Call request header", call.request().headers().toString());

        Log.d("Response raw header", response.headers().toString());
        Log.d("Response raw", String.valueOf(response.raw().body()));
        Log.d("Response code", String.valueOf(response.code()));

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("Response body", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
        }

        else  {
            Log.d("Response errorBody", String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: It might be more helpful to also show us the code where you are making the call.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla Thanks for answered me. I just updated the question :)

Comment: Can you change the line `Log.d("Response body", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));` into something like `Log.d("Response body", response.body().toString());` and let's see if you get the body as you expected. If it raises NullPointerException, then it might signal that the response is indeed null.

Comment: D/Response body: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@cda3c8a

Comment: Good, this means you are getting the response of type ResponseBody. See my answer for how to proceed.

Comment: @LucasPuerari can you tell me how you resolved this issue

Answer (score 3):

Since you are getting response which is not null (based on your latest command). I think you need to change your code as follows:

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.d("Call request", call.request().toString());
        Log.d("Call request header", call.request().headers().toString());
        Log.d("Response raw header", response.headers().toString());
        Log.d("Response raw", String.valueOf(response.raw().body()));
        Log.d("Response code", String.valueOf(response.code()));

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            //the response-body is already parseable to your ResponseBody object
            ResponseBody responseBody = (ResponseBody) response.body();
            //you can do whatever with the response body now... 
            String responseBodyString= responseBody.string();
            Log.d("Response body", responseBodyString);
        }
        else  {
            Log.d("Response errorBody", String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
        }
    }
```

Please give it a try and let me know if this helps.

Comment: I think it isn't change nothing
D/Response body: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@fde36f5

Comment: Please see the comment in the code, I just indicated that you could do whatever now that you have the response object (which is not null). Can you please include the code for the ReponseBody class?

Comment: ResponseBody isn't my class. I have imported from okhttp3.ResponseBody

Comment: OK, I have edited the answer - please try it out. Basically, I added the line `String responseBodyString= responseBody.string();` and I am logging the resulting string instead.

Comment: always the same problem :(

Comment: Just to recap, what are you trying to do with the response - because you started off with a `null` response body problem - which is now solved. So it seems now you need to explain what you are trying to do so we can advise further - but that would be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered: probably your API response object is wrong mapped. I had the same issue and after re-mapping my response correctly, my object wasn't null anymore.